# Obtaining boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying to numerically solve the three coupled PDEs;

$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t} = w + \nabla^2 \theta, \ \ \ \ \  (1)$

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = -RaPr\nabla^2_H\theta + \nabla^2 Q, \ \ \ \ \  (2)$

$\nabla^2 w = Q. \ \ \ \ \ (3)$

Which represent a linear stability analysis for temperature ($\theta$) and z-component velocity ($w$) perturbations for a fluid initially at rest between two infinite horizontal plates. I'm looking for a particular form of periodic solution such that;

$\nabla^2 = -a^2 + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}, \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$

$\nabla^2_H = -a^2. \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)$

$Ra$, $Pr$, and $a$ are parameters that do not depend on space or time. The domain is $z\in[0,1]$ and $t\in[0,\infty)$. I have the following boundary conditions: $\theta = w = \partial{w}/\partial{z} = 0 $. I am trying to convert these to obtain a boundary condition on $Q$. I have tried substituting $(4)$ into $(3)$ and taking $\partial/\partial z$ but this does not tell me anything about $Q$ and I know nothing about $\partial ^3
w/\partial z^3$. I am unsure on what I can try. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of this problem? And what is $Q^{(3)}$? Since $\theta$, $Q$ and $w$ are independent variables, I think that you can't obtain B.C. for $Q$ from the other B.C. Could you provide the physical context of this problem? It can be helpful to determine the B.C. for $Q$.

Comment: Sorry, $Q^{(3)} = \partial^3Q/\partial z^3$ - I will edit that part. The domain is $z\in[0,1]$ and $t\in[0,\infty)$. I am doing a linear stability analysis of perturbations to temperature ($\theta$) and the z-component of the velocity ($w$) for fluid initially at rest between two infinite horizontal plates. These boundary conditions represent fixed temperature, no slip conditions. I hope that helps.

Comment: And the B.C. you provided holds at $z=0$ and $z=1$?

Comment: Yes, I'll put this information in the question - my apologies. I will be solving this numerically, so I should add that I am demanding it holds. However, I'm unsure how to obtain a BC on Q from these to implement into my scheme.

Comment: Edit - $\partial^3Q/\partial z^3$ should be $\partial^3w/\partial z^3$, which I still know nothing about.

Comment: Somehow you need to relate $\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$ on the boundary to $Q$ on the boundary and I see no way to do that other than perhaps to recast to a weak formulation.

Comment: So equation (1) is energy conservation equation and equation (3) is a momentum conservation equation? What is equation (2)? And what does $Q$ represents?

Comment: @Ian Would it help that  $u, v, w = 0$ where $\vec{u} = (u,v,w)$? This is what I used to obtain the boundary condition $\partial{w}/\partial{z}=0$ using $\nabla\cdot\vec{u}=0$. I do not know how to cast PDEs into weak forms, it looks like I will have to go and read this.

Comment: Is the field divergence free *everywhere*, not just on the boundary?

Comment: Yes it is divergence free everywhere.